# postgis difference in terms of precision and performance between geography and geometry

Tags: python, database, postgresql, postgis, knn

I developed a telegram bot that match 2 users with the same language and when they both are looking for a partner with a postgres query.
I would like to add the **optional** ability to match users also depending on location (closest user).
Since it is an option i think i'm going to keep the column null by default and if the user sends his location i add it.
I'm going to implement this using postigs.
i have two questions:

1. is it better to use geography or geometry? because people can come from all over the world and i read in these cases it is better to use geography, but anyway i don't need any precise data, just to know who is the closest user and the distance between them (also approximately just to be indicated as an additional info when they are matched). I would like the query to be run fast (i mean less than 1 second). I was thinking to use KNN creating the index on the column and use ordered by <->. is it a good choice? what would you do for this? geometry or geography? is my idea fine?
2. Since, as i said, the field can be also NULL is the user doesn't want to provide the location i would like to give better priority to users that specified a location in the ordered by, if there is none with a specified location i take one random from the NULL values users. Is this possible with a query?

my bot is written in python if it can help.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to point 1 i think that this article will answer your question best

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html#PostGIS_Geography

About the speed - just create gist index on your geom/geog column and use st_Dwithin(geom1, geom2,100) and order result by st_distance(geom1,geom2) it will be fast enough until you will have tens of millions of users.

Point 2: Yes it is just union for example

```
select *, st_distance(u1.geom, u2.geom) dist from 
(Select u2.*
  from users u1, users u2
 where u1.id=1
   and u1.id<>u2.id
   and st_dwithin(u1.geom, u2.geom, 5000)
UNION
Select * , null dist
  from users
 where id<>1
   and geom is null
 LIMIT 1) a
order by dist
```

I miss other criteria liek gender, age etc. but of course use it in both selects